# linq to datasets - get a specific datarow

Tags: linq, dataset, datarow

i have a table with these columns:
errorCode (int)
errorDesc (Varchar)

i'm trying to get the datarow where errorCode is 5:

```
  DataRow resultCodeRow = (from resultCodesTableRow in resultCodesDT.AsEnumerable()
                                 where resultCodesTableRow.Field<int>("result_Code_colum_Name") == 5
                                 select resultCodesTableRow).Single();
```

why do i get the error:

"Specified cast is not valid."

how would you write it ?

Comment: What happens if you just fetch the field without trying to cast it to int? I suspect the value isn't *actually* an int, hence the problem.

Comment: Thats right. I suppose it is a varchar

Comment: you were all right - NUMBER in ORACLE is decimal in C# not int, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to decimal

**PK**

Comment: ah right then its decimal then in that case. Ive made the right changes